# issues running bash file from any directory

Tags: bash

Not sure if this is operator error or if I just don't understand enough of what I am trying to do.

I have created cleardl.sh and put it in ~/bin and have also added ~/bin into $PATH, when I run echo $PATH it shows that it was added correctly.

If I am in ~/bin I can run ./cleardl.sh and it runs like it should, but if I try to run it from anywhere else I get a file not found error.

I have tried to make an alias for it but this also doesn't work more than likely due to me not knowing how to do that either.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Moving the file to /usr/local/bin did get it working but then I deleted it to do some other tests and it kept working So it was likely me not having all the things correct at the same time.

Thanks for your help

Comment: please check below link, https://impurval.blogspot.com/2021/11/execute-custom-script-as-command.html

Comment: From "_anywhere else_" do you type `./cleardl.sh` or just `cleardl.sh`?

Comment: I have tried both ./cleardl.sh and cleardl.sh.  moving to /usr/local/bin worked but from what I had read I thought what I was doing was going to work aswell.

Comment: Can you show the output of `printenv PATH` in a terminal where typing `cleardl.sh` results in the _file not found_ error?

Comment: Ok, well I deleted the file I added into /usr/local/bin which should have stopped it working again so I could do that but now it is working fine...

Comment: Maybe you forgot `hash -r` after creating the file.

Comment: None of the guides I was looking at had hash -r so I didn't do that, should I be doing that after I create new files or now that it knows where my bin directory is should it work fine in the future?